# Double click does not open files or folders

Tags: mouse, touchpad, doubleclick

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, and I have noticed that double-clicking (with mouse or touchpad buttons) does not open files or folders.  Single click does select them, but the second click seems to have no effect.  If I click on a file or folders and then hit Enter, they do open as expected. Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm - unable to duplicate the problem. On my freshly-installed Ubuntu 18.04 test system, double-clicking seems to work properly.

Comment: Try this: Open **Settings**-> **Universal Access**. Then scroll down, you will see *'Double click delay'*, try to edit it and check if it works for you.

Comment: I have to adjust that on every PC I touch, Linux/Windows/Otherguys. singrium is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem, the solution is as @singrium outlined in the comments.  I am posting it as an answer so that people running into the same problem can more easily find the answer.

Open the **Settings** app, go to **Accessibility**, scroll down until you find the "Double-Click Delay" slider, and adjust it to what works best for you.

Apparently, the minimum setting completely disables double click.

Comment: huh didn't know it was renamed to Accessibility thanks for the edit @qwertyChouskie

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

*Settings* -> *Universal Access* 
and in *Pointing & Clicking*,   turned on *Mouse Keys* will resolve this problem.